# autocomplete jquery.get json doesn't complete

Tags: json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm having trouble with autocomplete, usign JSON data.
I'm getting the right response from the callback, but the autocomplete doesn't work properly. For example, when I type "Lon" I get this response:

```
[{\"value\":\"Dijon, (DIJ)\",\"code\":\"DIJ\"},{\"value\":\"Longview, (GGG)\",\"code\":\"GGG\"},{\"value\":\"Long Island, (HAP)\",\"code\":\"HAP\"},{\"value\":\"Islip, (ISP)\",\"code\":\"ISP\"},{\"value\":\"Long Banga, (LBP)\",\"code\":\"LBP\"},{\"value\":\"Londrina, (LDB)\",\"code\":\"LDB\"},{\"value\":\"Londonderry, (LDY)\",\"code\":\"LDY\"},{\"value\":\"Long Beach, (LGB)\",\"code\":\"LGB\"},{\"value\":\"Long Lellang, (LGL)\",\"code\":\"LGL\"},{\"value\":\"Long Akah, (LKH)\",\"code\":\"LKH\"},{\"value\":\"Londra, (All airports - LON)\",\"code\":\"LON\"},{\"value\":\" - Londra, Gatwick Arpt (LGW)\",\"code\":\"LGW\"},{\"value\":\" - Londra, London City Arpt (LCY)\",\"code\":\"LCY\"},{\"value\":\" - Londra, Stansted Arpt (STN)\",\"code\":\"STN\"},{\"value\":\" - Londra, London Biggin Hill Arpt (BQH)\",\"code\":\"BQH\"},{\"value\":\" - Londra, Heathrow (LHR)\",\"code\":\"LHR\"}]
```

But my autocomplete just adds Longview and Long Island. 
The tricky thing is that after I keep typing "Lond", the autocomplete works perfect, I delete the "d", the autocomplete works perfect, it completes all the data from above.

Where do I go wrong...?
Here's my code:

```
$("#destination2").keyup(function(){
    var term = $("#destination2").val();
    //var query_type = $("#form_type").val();

    jQuery.get('http://online.bileteavion.com.ro/q_travel_online_api/misc/hotels.autocomplete.php?query_type=flight&term='+term, function(data) {

                    data = eval('['+data.responseText.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]+']');
                    var source = $.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.value,
                        value: item.value,
                        id: item.id,
                        iata: item.iata
                            }
                    });

                    $("#destination2").autocomplete({
                        source: source,
                        minLength: 3,
                        search: function(event, ui) {
                            $('#loading-spinner').show();
                                },
                        change: function(event, ui) {
                            //console.log(ui.item);
                            if( !ui.item ) {
                                $(this).val("");
                                $("input[name='cityId']").val("");
                                $("input[name='destinationIataCode']").val("");
                                $("input[name='destination']").val("");

                            }
                        },
                        open: function() {
                                $('#loading-spinner').hide();
                        },
                        select: function(event, ui) {
                            $("input[name='cityId']").val(ui.item.id);
                            $("input[name='destinationIataCode']").val(ui.item.iata);
                            $("input[name='destination']").val(ui.item.value);
                            $(this).blur();
                        }
                }); 

                }
    );

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jquery.autocomplete` is not a function to call every single time you want to display the autocomplete dialog.

You should call `jquery.autocomplete` only once during initializion, to equip your input field with a full mechanism which allows autocompleting - and which will take care of the "keyup" event.

To achieve what you need, you should use a callback with the `source` option.

Here is how :

Instead of :

```
$("#destination2").keyup(function(){
     ...
     jquery.get(<url>, function(data){
          var source = ...

          $("#destination2").autocomplete({
             source: source
             minLength: ...
             search: ...
             open: ...
             select: ...
          })
     })
})
```

You should write :

```
$("#destination2").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
       //request is an obj containing infos on what is typed
       //response is a callback, which should be called if you want to display hints
       jQuery.get(url + request.term, function(data){
           var source = ...
           response(source);
       })
    }
    minLength: ...
    search: ...
    open: ...
    select: ...
})
```

You should check the [Remote JSONP datasource](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) from the docs.

Comment: My only problem that remains is with New York. When i type "New Y", I get no results(checked in Firebug), although if I test it separately, it works. Does it have anything to do with maxRows?

Comment: It also applies for all cities that have 2 or more words. :(

Comment: This has to do with the way the server handles your request. From what I understand, you do not have access to the server code. Read more carefully the specifications of the web service to understand how you should build your query, or ask tech support.

Comment: As an added note : try to avoid calling "eval", especially on a foreign data source. If the result is a well-formed JSON object, use jQuery.parseJSON ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ ).

Comment: That's right, I don't have access to the server. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my site. Works quite well.

```
 $("#id").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://online.bileteavion.com.ro/q_travel_online_api/misc/hotels.autocomplete.php',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            //values to pass to server. in your case: query_type & term
                            term: request.term,
                            query_type: 'flight'
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(eval(data), function (item) {
                                return {
                                      //map values as you previously did
                                      label: item.value,
                                      value: item.value,
                                      id: item.id,
                                      iata: item.iata
                                }
                            })
                            );
                        }
                    })
                },
                minLength: 3,
                search: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#loading-spinner').show();
                },
                change: function(event, ui) {
                     //console.log(ui.item);
                     if( !ui.item ) {
                        $(this).val("");
                        $("input[name='cityId']").val("");
                        $("input[name='destinationIataCode']").val("");
                        $("input[name='destination']").val("");
                     }
                },
                open: function() {
                        $('#loading-spinner').hide();
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("input[name='cityId']").val(ui.item.id);
                    $("input[name='destinationIataCode']").val(ui.item.iata);
                    $("input[name='destination']").val(ui.item.value);
                    $(this).blur();
                }
            });
```

Comment: The url is on your server? Thanks!

Comment: ... i'm sorry but what? I'm properly confused by that comment. I'll update my code sample to reflect parts your code?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. In my case, "url: 'http://online.bileteavion.com.ro/q_travel_online_api/misc/hotels.autocomplete.php'" is not on my server, but a foreign one. I had to "cross domains" to make it work, although online.bileteavion.com.ro is a subdomain for bileteavion.com.ro.